# What are the risks with Project Lombok?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, boilerplate, lombok

I'm coming up with performance goals for the new year, and I thought I'd be fun to put a goal to reduce the size of the code base, especially boilerplate. One action I've come up with to address this is to use [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) to make beans as short as they should be. But I have a habit of overlooking downsides to new software and approaches, so I'm relying on the Stack Overflow community: Can anyone tell me why Lombok is a bad idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use Project Lombok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok)

Comment: Maybe interessant: https://medium.com/@gabor.liptak/some-dangers-of-using-lombok-d759fc8f701f

Comment: https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/dont-use-lombok/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A major downside is IDE support.  Since Lombok is not actually a language change, and since your IDE only understands java, you will need an IDE that supports Lombok to get things working right.  As of now, <s>that's only Eclipse</s> that includes Eclipse and IntelliJ.  If you use eclipse that might be ok, but remember that you are making a decision for future developers as well.

I'd suggest you consider moving some of your code into a less ceremonial language such as groovy.  We've had success moving some of our business logic and models into groovy and it works really smoothly.

Comment: Wrong about only Eclipse: I use Project Lombok in Netbeans Dev just fine. And I think they support other IDE's as well

Comment: Things may be improving, but the criticism still remains that you will need explicit IDE support to use an IDE with a Lombok project.  The point your project no longer qualifies as strictly Java code.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I use Eclipse but some of the other Devs use IDEA, which doesn't yet appear to support Lombok.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Both IntelliJ (via plugin) and NetBeans supports Lombok.

Comment: A related question: "Is it safe to use Project Lombok?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok

Comment: Update 2021 the latest version of Intellij Idea supports lombok out of the box starting from 2020.3. I don't feel its a problem with IDE anymore. 
As long as everyone in the team agrees with using Lombok it could only help in speeding up development time or slow it down if everyone in the team does what they want and there is no consensus on what should be the "Team Standard"

Comment: The very fact that you need an IDE support shows for me that Lombok is an antipatern.

Answer (score 44):

A limitation of Lombok is the fact that it is closely tied to the java compiler. Since the annotation processor API only allows creation of new files during the compilation (and not the modification of the existing files) lombok uses that API as a entry point to modify the java compiler. Unfortunately these modifications of the compiler make heavy usage of non-public APIs. Using lombok may be a good idea but you must be aware that upgrading your compiler may break your code. The probability is low but I always feel uncomfortable using non-public APIs.

Comment: Very good point. History of Java 8 + Lombok showed us that this can be a problem.

Comment: For now, they fixed it and it works with Java 9 but not yet with Java 10.

Answer (score 33):

In my opinion source code in "Java+Lombok" is not Java source code anymore. I see it as something similar Borland company made many years ago in their Borland C++ Builder IDE for VCL - they introduced "properties" in C++ code effectively introducing some kind of a new programming language that wasn't C++ anymore (not C++ in sense of standard of C++ language). Sources using "Java+Lombok" are not valid sources in sense of Java language specification. Moreover I think annotations were not designed to influence language semantic.

Comment: I agree with this answer more than the accepted one. Lombok isn't restricting IDE usage anymore. It's just bringing Java into the modern days. Without Lombok, I would be screaming for my company to change the codebase to something less verbose, like Kotlin.

Comment: Hopefully, with Java 21 less people will be regarding Lombok.

Answer (score 25):

One potential disadvantage to something like Lombok is that with the setters/getters "missing", source tools may not "recognize" aspects of the resulting object that give it "bean" qualities, since those qualities only manifest in the compiled class.

Another disadvantage is that it's Yet Another piece of "black magic" within the tool chain. Fortunately, it seems to be a rather benign piece (I have not used it), and the fact that it happens at compile time rather than runtime is actually a blessing (IMHO). But, you're not going to be able to reuse or share your code without the project since it's adding artifacts to your code base. So, while the compiled class file may be a "POJO", I'd argue that your source code is NOT a POJO.

Neither of these are crippling downsides, rather just aspects to be aware of looking forward.

Comment: You may use http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html in order to get vanilla classes.

Comment: I fully agree on the "black magic" terminology. If you're familiar with it then you'll know what's going on, but if you're new to it, then it looks like your code is lying to you, a potential source of WTF moments

Answer (score 6):

It's a third party library, and there are developers who don't know it well.

IDE should support annotations processing (there are plugins for IDEA and Eclipse).

As was mentioned above, your code will be without getters/setters. It leads to sonar/checkstyle violations.

Comment: There are documented ways around this already - use delombok before running sonar/checkstyle.
But anyway, do you really want to have code coverage on your POJOs?!

Comment: It's not about POJO coverage. Sonar says smth like `make this field private and add getter`.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, The most obvious risk with Project Lombok is that when you decide to use lombok, you also decide that everyone else who deals with your code uses lombok. This is a true statement for all libraries, but Lombok is special in that it is a build-time dependency and your IDE needs plugins to figure out what is going on. That means anyone who has reason to touch your code ex. someone trying to debug weird behavior, etc.) needs to know how to set it up and how it works. That can be a little frustrating.

Comment: Very much so. This is especially applicable where people may be coming from different programming backgrounds, namely non-JVM languages, where lombok is far less known.

Answer (score 6):

To add to other responses.

The main reason to not use it is a new `record` keyword added as experimental feature in Java 14. Java 16 brings `records` out of preview which will make project Lombok obsolete in most cases.

Since Java 14 one is able able to write:

```
record Book(String title, String author, String isbn);
```

which gives automatically access to the constructor, getters/setter, hashCode, equals and toString methods without any annotations.

Comment: Record classes does not allow inheritance and does not have setters. Plus, once you instantiate it you can not change its state.

Comment: In almost all cases those restrictions are good things. Nevertheless it's true that because of these restrictions, `record` is not a drop in replacement for lombok except maybe specifically for `@lombok.Value`. Even then, it has some differences.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by user [@Jcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432589/jcs) in another answer, i would like to add more.

In our project we, are using mapstruct which is used to generate mapper classes, before the code is compiled, using mvn generate-sources command, this is done at process phase using maven processor plugin.

project lombok adds the bytecode for the getter/setter in class file at compile phase.

since process phase is executed before the compile, it finds that there is no getter/setter available in class.

There are some workarounds available to execute compile phase more than one.
See this [git hub ticket](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/510) for more details.

Note : I am using STS ide by Spring and it is supported by lombok :)