# Automatically create builder for class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, builder

Is there a way to use an *automatic builder* to create builder ([Joshua Bloch's Builder Pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)) for classes in `Eclipse`? For example an option in the menu, a plugin or something else. I could not find anything under "*`Refactor`*".

Comment: A quick google search for `eclipse plugin builder pattern` got me (among others) https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: Unless you can somehow achieve this by making a template, Annotation Processing is the only thing I can think of. It allows you to create an annotation, such as `@Build`, then create a processor to look for that annotation in your source code, raise an error when there's no builder class (optional), and allow the client to generate the builder code similar to how one automatically declared unimplemented methods. As for plugins, I'm sure you know the rules by now /: It sucks, but you can't request for tools on here

Comment: @Dirk - I do not like your answer. It's not possible to downvote the comments but I am virtually giving you -1. Maybe you should not be happy just with the pure existence of a link found by google. I have tried the Fluent Builder Generator and it has not been updated for 10 years and generates quite complicated code instead of a nice simple builder.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I think you have misunderstood the point of my comment. The OP hasn't shown any effort to find an answer by himself. I only wanted to point out the fact that some simple googling got me answers (plural, that's why i have written 'among others'). I know that a "here do you have a link" isn't an answer - that's why i have put it in a comment. Maybe i better had voted to close...

Comment: @Dirk: I would not close it! I did myself some research and I have not found any useful eclipse plugin for the builder - that's how I came to this post. So I would enjoy if someone may *answer* the OP's question, not to close it! You may show your ability to use google and find something really working, configurable and up-to-date and post it as an answer :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Using my google foo? I'm sorely tempted :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek It's not an eclipse plugin but maybe you'll give it a try: https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder

Comment: Eclipse badly needs this functionality. Someone with more patience than me please file an issue ;)

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat actually there is a bug report, hidden inside Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458364

Comment: One problem of lombok. It generate all in compile time. This can be a perfomance neck. Use with caution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe I am late to the party.

Eclipse on its own does not provide a way to generate code to support builder pattern. However it can be extended through plugins to enhance the functionality.

There is this plugin that I use this:

https://github.com/henningjensen/bpep

Edit: After 5 years, revisiting this topic, would recommend to use lombok that has become industry standard anyway and is also IDE agnostic ==> would work if your team mates use a variety of IDEs.
Check out this annotation. You could also include pattern [inheritance](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance) among classes.

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
// or you could use this for inheritance
@SuperBuilder
```

Comment: Unfortunately Google Code is closing, so this link will likely become invalid in a few months. Is this project available somewhere else?

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't seem to work anymore. It creates a builder but seems to be unable to list the fields.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: I just tried it on eclipse mars and it worked for me.

Comment: @Khanna111 It is not working for me also. Using eclipse luna

Comment: I used this plugin on `Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)` and it works. Also this plugin has an advantage which does not need to annotations.

Comment: This plugin does not work when used on subclasses. The builder does not include the fields of a superclass.

Comment: This Builder also only uses non final fields.I do not know why it works like that. But still the most usable builder for me.

Answer (score 29):

You may want to look at [lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotations to generate builders without the boiler plate code. For example:

```
@Builder
public class MyPojo {
    private String name;
}

MyPojoBuilder.builder().name("yourame").build();
```

The limitation is that this doesn't seem to work with abstract classes.

Comment: A definitie +1 for directing me to a great project that I had never seen before. This solves the problem and simplifies some of the other hassles with generating boilerplate code as well :).

Comment: Impressive capabilities. Wonder why lombok isn't popular?

Comment: I found this answer when looking for an alternative to Lombok because the `@Builder` annotation still (in April 2017) does not work for members which are provided by parent classes (as Jaco mentions).

Comment: @BasilMusa whether lombok is or is not popular you should read "What are the risks with Project Lombok?" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589184/what-are-the-risks-with-project-lombok    and also "Is it safe to use Project Lombok?" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok

Answer (score 17):

I currently use **Spark Builder Generator** with Eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) and it works well.

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sparkbuildergenerator
- https://github.com/helospark/SparkBuilderGenerator

> You can set the preferences under:
> Window->Preferences->Java->Spark Builder Generator

Comment: Yes Spark builder works very well. And it has a lot of options. Like stage builder. Have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Try https://github.com/vojtek/write-it-once

```
package ${cls.package.name};

public class ${cls.shortName}Builder {

public static ${cls.name}Builder builder() {
    return new ${cls.name}Builder();
}
<% for(field in cls.fields) {%>
private ${field.type.name} ${field.name};
<% } %>
<% for(field in cls.fields) {%>
public ${cls.name}Builder ${field.name}(${field.type.name} ${field.name}) {
    this.${field.name} = ${field.name};
    return this;
}
<% } %>
public ${cls.name} build() {
    final ${cls.name} data = new ${cls.name}();
<% for(field in cls.fields) {%>
    data.${field.setter.name}(this.${field.name});
<% } %>
    return data;
}
}
```

Comment: its quite simple solution - create separate separate project with templates, and generate java classes form main

Answer (score 2):

You could add your own template window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> templates and this will be activated with the content proposal but not by refactor action

Comment: I do not think that you could write a template for a builder pattern. Even if it would work, it is a bad idea, because templates do not provide a way to be updated, you would have to manually delete the code and reapply the template.