# Faster way to generate all possible constructors in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

```
class Formulas{
    private double x=0, y=0, z=0, t=0, theta=0, v=0, a=0;
}
```

Assume I have a class similar to the one above and want to overload the constructor for all possible combinations of the given fields. Is there a faster way to generate all necessary constructors using Eclipse?

Comment: isnt creating object and then setting up values faster better stronger?

Comment: Builder pattern all the way!

Comment: If you tried to write those constructors manually you'd immediately notice why this couldn't work at all independent what tool you use. Which field should be set by `new Formulas(10.0)`?

Answer (score 6):

Consider two possible constructors:

`public Formulas(double x);
public Formulas(double theta);`

They have the *same signature* so ultimately the compiler can't tell them apart, so this is illegal.

The short answer is it can't be done.  Consider a Builder or a Factory pattern instead.

You could also "divide and conquer" the arguments.  I'm not sure what your v and a are, but, if they were angular values associated with theta, you could use a Point3D and an Angle3D class to hold the 6 inputs, and have a constructor

`public Formulas(Point3D point, Angle3D angle)`

Answer (score 5):

Much cleaner and more readable, the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example).

As for "a fast way", check out [Automatically create builder for class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493898/automatically-create-builder-for-class-in-eclipse).

```
public class Formulas {
    private double x=0, y=0, z=0, t=0, theta=0, v=0, a=0;

    public Formulas() {

    }

    public Formulas withX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }

    public Formulas withY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }

    // repeat

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // repeat...

}
```

---

Usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Formulas f = new Formulas().withX(2).withY(4);
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", f.getX(), f.getY()); // 2.0 4.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a tool to generate a constructor using fields but not to generate all possible combinations of constructors.

To generate a constructor using some or all available fields, go to `Source > Generate Constructor using Fields` and select the fields you want. then click `OK` and the constructor is automatically generated.

Note: Two constructors with the same parameter type with different variable names are not accepted in Java. 
For instance:

```
Constructor(Object parameterOne){ ... }
Constructor(Object parameterTwo){ ... }
```

Will not compile.