# Using code generation in order to generate test data

Tags: java, debugging, code-generation

I often come across situations were I want to save the content of a large object graph (run-time or during debugging) to a set of statements recreating this object graph. This can then be used as test data in unit test cases.

[image: screenshot of debugger]

Taken that leafs of the object graph are standard types (`String`, `BigDecimal`, `Date`, etc) and the branches follow the bean convention (getters, setters, empty constructor), it should be possible to generate this kind of file (e.g. TestData.java):

```
   public static Car createCar() {

    Wheel wheel1 = new Wheel();
    wheel1.setTypePressure( 2.1f );
    Wheel wheel2 = new Wheel();
    wheel2.setTypePressure( 2.3f );
    Wheel wheel3 = new Wheel();
    wheel3.setTypePressure( 2.0f );
    Wheel wheel4 = new Wheel();
    wheel4.setTypePressure( 2.8f );
    List<Wheel> wheels = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( wheel1, wheel2, wheel3, wheel4 ) );

    Brake brake = new Brake();
    brake.setBrakeType( BrakeType.PLAIN );

    Car car = new Car();
    car.setBrake( brake );
    car.setWheels( wheels );
    car.setColor( "blue" );

    return car;
}
```

It would be really great to plug this directly into a debug session somehow, but a few drop-in statements writing as result the "java object graph creation code with content" output to `System.out` would also work.

So, how can I realize this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice idea, but (probably opinionated) not the best solution.

Yes, that data *could* be transformed into a Java program; which then needs to be saved, compiled, ...

Then questions arise such as: do you want to keep source code around, or compiled code; what about versioning (of data, or the underlying JRE)?

Long story short: Java code isn't a very convenient format to represent **data**. Thus: instead of turning your data into Java code, turn it into some JSON representation for example.

The point is: when your classes are really following "bean style"; and they already have getters/setters/default constructors - then *any* decent JSON parser library should work "out of the box". You throw your Car object at it; and out comes nice, standard JSON. Then you write a little helper tool that reads such files and turns them back into Car objects. Done.

That is the way to go (and this advise comes from somebody who worked on a system where the architect wanted exactly that what you are asking for; and we spent a lot of time and pain to get there ... but that was more than 10 years ago; and in 2017 you simply don't do that any more).

Given your latest comment (as you are mainly interested in unit testcode); I would suggest to look into using the **builder** pattern here.

So that your code would boil down to

```
new CarBuilder().wheel(new WheelBuilder(). ...
```

The nice thing about that: there are various ways to **generate** such builders for you; for example project [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) has a @Builder annotation!

In any case, the market for generating builders automatically is pretty [rich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493898/automatically-create-builder-for-class-in-eclipse)!

Comment: I concur. I also propose dropping a simple example of, say, GSON at work. It is incredible what you can do with a one-liner, and it will probably convince OP more than just stating that it is easy.

Comment: If there's no out-of-the-box solution I will try JSON. My only concern is that data kept in a seperate JSON file from your (Junit) test code is not subjected to refactoring. Ergo: if my model changes (attribute names, entity names) refactor will automatically tackle the java solution. Admit: if the structure changes I'll have a problem anyway.

Comment: @tucuxi. I just tried on my small example. It is indeed amazing.

Comment: @sjaak After some more thinking, and your updates; I put up another update for you. Feel free to accept/upvote if that matches your needs better ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat: I started to play around with using JSON as you initially suggested. Thanks for that suggestion. I think that's the way to go (and feels pretty lean). I'm familiar with Lombok, builder patterns and / or object mother. I did not know however Lombok provided builders-out-of-the box :). Worthwhile to take a shot at it.  But first: json :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any IDE plugin that would do that, and I couldn't find one by Googling.  In the absence of an existing plugin (for your IDE) written by someone else, the answer to your question:

> How can I realize this in the most efficient way?

depends on whether it is more efficient to *develop* the plugin (yourself!) or just continue with writing the test cases by hand.

My guess is that the latter will be more efficient.

---

Also I agree with @GhostCat's.  If your testcases are "data intensive", it would be better to choose / implement a text-based serial format for the test data, and express the test data that way.  In my experience, it is easier to read / modify test data expressed that way than test data that is coded as a bunch of Java calls to construct object graphs.  It is important that your test cases are not "write only".

Comment: Thanks. I went for the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at persisting your graph to some human-readable, yet parsable form.  XML may be your best choice as the syntax allows for cross-document references, but any format would work - even a custom syntax.  This would let you persist and transmit graphs at runtime while supporting easy-to-modify and -replicate test graphs for unit tests.